# Linux Distributive With Global Menu and UbuntuOne For Netbook

Tags: unity, ubuntu-one, appmenu, desktop-environments, alternative

I like very much global menu in previous versions of Ubuntu. But Unity is too slow for my Eee PC. So now I am looking for some alternative Desktop Environments or Distributions where there is global menu available. But at the same time there should be UbuntuOne service working too, as I use it pretty often.
Could you, please, suggest what should I try out?

I also use keyboard shortcuts very much and so I guess they should be configurable, and try not to use touchpad at all. So big icons like in gnome-shell and Unity are not a good option.

Comment: Ubuntu one is for Ubuntu and derivatives, spin offs only

Comment: And you can install whatever DE you want.

Comment: Have you tried unity 2d?

Comment: Yes, but it is much less configurable than unity. For example, I could not find how to configure the size of the left panel buttons.

Comment: Have you solved this question?

Comment: No, using Precise with unity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out xubuntu-desktop. There is now a global-menu plugin available for XFCE.

See [OMG ! XFCE Global Menu [PPA Ready]](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907070609/http://gtk-apps.org/content/show.php/OMG+!+XFCE+Global+Menu+%5BOneiric+Only%5D?content=146102).

Answer (score 0):

Try enlightenment e17.
It's a great lightweight DE that I use on my old Atom netbook.

Everything apart from software centre is quite snappy.